# For loop only returns first line of textfile

Tags: python, for-loop, text-files

I am trying to make a program where i have to check if certain numbers are in use in a text file. The problem is that my for loop only loops trough the first line, instead of every line. How can i solve this? I've already used readlines() but that has not worked for me. This is the code and i've got a text file with: 1;, 2; and 3;, each on a seporated line. Hope someone can help!

```
if int(keuze) == 2:
    def new_safe():
        with open('fa_kluizen.txt', 'r') as f:
            for number in f:
                return number

    print(new_safe())
```

My text File:

```
# TextFile
    1;
    2;
    3;
```

Comment: What are you expecting the return value to be? `readlines()` will return a list of lines, which you said didn't work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning too early (at first iteration).

You can read all lines in a list while cleaning the data and then return that list.

```
with open('fa_kluizen.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = [line.strip() for line in f]
return data
```

Also most of the time its bad to create a function inside an if-statement.
Maybe you can add a little bit more information about what you want to achieve.

Comment: Except for calling `strip()`, this is the same as `return f.readlines()`, which they said didn't work for them.

Answer (score 0):

you are returning the first line you encounter, and by doing so, the program exits the current function and of course, the loop.

One way to do it is:

```
def new_safe():
    with open('fa_kluizen.txt', 'r') as f:
        return f.read().splitlines()
```

Which returns a each line as a list of the strings.

Output:

```
['1;', '2;', '3;']
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as `f.readlines()`, which they said didn't work for them.

Comment: The problem wasn't the reading functionality (with or without `readlines()`), the problem was with the in-loop return statement.

Answer (score 0):

That's beacause "return numbrer", Try

```
if int(keuze) == 2:
    def new_safe():
        my_list = []
        with open('fa_kluizen.txt', 'r') as f:
            for number in f:
                my_list.append(number)
        return my_list
```